# jquery value from checked radio group with numerous similar groups

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a variable number of similar radio groups, I need to loop through them sequentially via class and output selected values. JS Fiddle below. I realize I could find it more directly by using #ID instead of .Class, but without all the details, I need to go this route.

In the process of creating the question, I figured out the length of b array is 9, so to get the 2nd group I use b[2*(# radios in group)], but that seems kind of hackish. Any other recommendation?

```
<div id="1">
<input type = "radio" name="a0" value="1" class="a" checked="checked" >1</input>
<input type = "radio" name="a0" value="2" class="a">2</input>
<input type = "radio" name="a0" value="3" class="a">3</input>
<div>
<div id="2">
<input type = "radio" name="a1" value="1" class="a">1</input>
<input type = "radio" name="a1" value="2" class="a" checked="checked">2</input>
<input type = "radio" name="a1" value="3" class="a">3</input>
<div>
<div id="3">
<input type = "radio" name="a2" value="1" class="a">1</input>
<input type = "radio" name="a2" value="2" class="a">2</input>
<input type = "radio" name="a2" value="3" class="a" checked="checked">3</input>
<div>
<button onclick="getValue();">Get values</button>

<script>
function getValue() {
var b = $(".a");
alert( $('input:radio[name=' + $(b[2*3]).attr("name") + ']:checked').val() );    

}


</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cycle4passion/6c0q0kum/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `$.each` function to iterate through.

```
function getValue() {
    $("input:radio.a:checked").each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    }); 
}
```

#### See

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c0q0kum/2/)

[jQuery each documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with an array of the checked inputs:

```
// iterate over the <input> elements of
// class 'a' and which are checked,
// forming a map:
var checked = $('input.a:checked').map(function () {

    // return the value of the current <input>
    // of the collection of elements:
    return this.value;

// convert the map to an Array:
}).get();

console.log(checked); // ["1", "2", "3"];
```

If you'd rather produce an object, where the name is the key and the input's value is the key-value:

```
// create an Object:
var checked = {};

// iterate, using each(), over the checked
// inputs of class-name 'a':
$('input.a:checked').each(function () {

    // setting a property (this.name) on
    // the named Object (checked), and
    // setting its value to the <input>
    // value (this.value):
    checked[this.name] : this.value;
});

console.log(checked); // { 'a0' : "1", 'a1' : "2", 'a2' : "3" }
```

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 0):

I found it a little more straightforward to find the enclosing divs, each holding the radio groups and select like:

2nd group:

```
$(b[1]).children('input[type=radio]:checked').val()
```

A JSFiddle is included. https://jsfiddle.net/cycle4passion/6c0q0kum/5/